# Reference Error while executing jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I am working on jasmine tests for a button on rails which changes html dir attribute. My click functionality is working fine but when I run my tests, I do see reference error. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

view.html.erb

```
<p><%= button_tag 'Convert', remote: 'true' %></p>
```

convert.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').on('click', function (){
   $('html').attr('dir', getElement);
 });

  function getElement() {
   return this.getAttribute('dir') === 'rtl' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl';
 }
});
```

Here is my jasmine test file.

conversion_spec.js

```js
//= require jquery

describe('#rtl', function (){
  describe("Testing spies", function () {
    it("Should replace the return value of function being spied on", function () {
      // Arrange
      var myApp = new getElement();
      spyOn(myApp, "getAttribute").and.returnValue('rtl');
      
      // Act
      var result = myApp.useFlagForSomething();
      
      // Assert
      expect(result).toBe("rtl");
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my error message:

```html
Failures:
          #rtl Testing spies Should replace the return value of function being spied on

          ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getElement in http://localhost:45463/__spec__/conversion_spec.js (line 28)
          ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getElement
    at http://localhost:45463/__spec__/conversion_spec.js:28
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:45463/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1789)
    at http://localhost:45463/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1777
    at http://localhost:45463/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1762
    at http://localhost:45463/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:627
    at http://localhost:45463/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:357

1 spec, 1 failure
```

Comment: It looks like your `getElement` function is defined within an anonymous function. It will only be available within that function. Your jasmine test doesn't know anything about it, so you get a reference error when you try to use it.

Comment: But in my support file jasmine.yml I gave a reference to the script then it should know about it right?

Comment: Try moving your `getElement` function outside of the `$(document).ready` call. By defining that function within another function its only available within the outer function.

Comment: Tried moving it outside the `$(document).ready`. Now i am getting a different error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.getAttribute('dir')')`

Comment: Ah, I see now. You're using `getElement` as the callback for a jQuery call. It doesn't make sense to test it as you're doing now. in `getElement` `this` refers to the element found by the jQuery call. Using it as a constructor function doesn't follow

Comment: But how can i test the attributes for html dir attribute?